# is argument type int is not iterable

Tags: python, data-science

Post=list( df ['Posts'])
Post 1=list()
for num in Post:
if 'k' in num:
new_num=1000*float(num.replace('k',''))
Post1.append(new_num)
else:
Post1.append(float(num))
df['Posts']=Post1

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [37], in <cell line: 3>()
2 Post1=list()
3 for num in Post:
----> 4     if 'k' in num:
5         new_num=1000*float(num.replace('k',''))
6         Post1.append(new_num)

TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Used range function but got error only tried both in colab and jupiter

Answer (score 0):

Pandas allows applying conditional statements directly to a dataframe column. Highly recommend trying out:

- pandas apply and
- python lambda.

```py
df = df.apply(lambda x: 
     1000*float(x['Posts'].replace('k','') 
    if 'k' in x['Posts'] 
    else float(x['Posts']) 
, axis=1 )
```

Disclaimer: sudo code only written while on bus without being run